# VS2022 Experimental Visual Studio attempts to load x86 version

Tags: visual-studio-2022, vsix

I have a VSIX extension upgraded from VS2017 to VS2022. Although the extension and project are specified as AnyCPU when I attempt to start the experimental version it looks for a non existent x86 DevEnv.exe. I have looked everywhere to find an x86 reference.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried Reset Experimental Instance 2022 from the start menu - no luck.

Comment: I found part of the problem the "Debug.Start External Program" was the offender: It specified the old VS2017 version.